# calling objects at tkinter frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I need help with tkinter frames handling and calling objects into it. Here's my example :

```
from tkinter import *

class Main(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.frame_one = Frame(self)
        self.frame_two = Frame(self)
        self.frame_one.pack()
        self.frame_two.pack()
        self.someclassobj = SomeClass(self.frame_one)
        self.someclassobj.pack()

class SomeClass(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.frame = Frame(master)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.btn = Button(self.frame, text='click', command=self.btn_func)
        self.btn.pack()

    def btn_func(self):
        Main.someclassobjtwo = SomeClassTwo(Main.frame_two)
        Main.someclassobjtwo.pack()



class SomeClassTwo(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.frame = Frame(master)
        self.msg = Label(self.frame, text='some msg')
        self.msg.pack()

app = Main()
app.mainloop()
```

I need to call object of `SomeClassTwo` at `Main.frame_two` , but i get `AttributeError: type object 'Main' has no attribute 'frame_two'`

I really don't know why that happens.

Comment: The `Main` class doesn't have a `frame_two` attribute, so `Main.frame_two` doesn't make sense. (Hint: recall that there is a difference between a class and an instance of a class)

Comment: Thanks, I finally realized what the problem is